# Placeholder - Mini-Mod

Tags: app, placeholder

Mini-Mod is planned to be an app that helps the community moderate content

This also has automated features which require `write_access`

This is simply the placeholder which the app will be connected to

Comment: When's it going to be released? :)

Comment: @user17242583 I'm working alone, it will probably be released by late December